Printing multiple files with the same printer settings
I need to print multiple PDF documents with customized printer settings (in my case: two-sided, with staples) at once.
Can you help me?
My system is 10.13.6.
I've tried different things so far, but no one works.

The "select and command P" method does not work because the default setting of my printer does not include the staples.

I've tried changing the default settings of my printer but I am not able to do it.

I tried two apps: "Easy PDF Printer" (which does not work on my Mac) and "Batch Print PDF" (which put only one staple on all the printed documents instead of 50 staples).



Generally speaking printers that offer stapling/holepunch/collating/etc. have drivers available that supports all of their enterprise level features. You need to add the make and model of printer to your question. Also have you checked for a driver installer for the printer?

I already have this special driver

If you have the "special driver" provided by the printer manufacturer, then the functions should be available if you set them correctly.

The functions work perfectly but I want to do batch printing.

Define “batch printing “ and usually the driver supports everything the printer does. Have you contacted the printer mfgs support?

I want to print 50 documents with the same settings. I have not contacted the support.

Can't you change the default printer settings to add stapling? After printing the 50 documents, you can disable it again. See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl09087a64/14.0/mac/14.0 for details.

I can follow all the steps described in this page, except the very last one: "With your default printer selected, choose Default Settings in the Presets menu to set up which presets the printer should use by default."

I might have found the solution: press option and enter while validating a printing job. That would change the default settings. I haven’t tested yet.

I've tested... and it does not work.

Please add the details refined in the comments to the question with an edit

Whats is unclear in “How to print 50 documents at the same time with staples?”?

The answer to that would be "install whatever driver your printer needs and print", but I fully agree that this doesn't help you because you've tried all the obvious things and it still doesn't work. What would help the community here to propose the non-obvious things is to know more about your setup (e.g. which printer, what specific steps you've tried etc.). Part of this is already in the comments where it can be deleted anytime, having it in the question itself helps a lot.

I’m angry at people who close questions! What’s your problem? I will edit the question.

@nohillside The answer wouldn’t be that. You missed the part “I want to print 50 different documents at the same time with the same settings”. My question might not be clear enough.

Have you saved a Print Preset with the custom settings that you want?

Thanks for the edit. „I've tried changing the default settings of my printer but I am not able to do it.“ would be the way to go, so where actually does it not work, what did fail when you tried to do it that way?

@benwiggy Yes, I have saved the settings I want to use.

@nohillside I have no clue on how to do that (changing the default settings of the printer).

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl09087a64/14.0/mac/14.0, but if I read the comments correctly , you skipped the last step.

Would a CLI/Terminal-based approach work as well for you?

Yes, a Terminal-based approach is ok for me. I don’t know what CLI means.

Command line interface :-) ok, need to check later

@nohillside The last step does not exist on my os I think.

Ah, https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/save-your-print-settings-to-use-later-mchl09087a64/10.13/mac/10.13 then. Which indeed doesn't have a way to set a default. Well, this also makes the Terminal approach more difficult because I have no way to test this.

Have you tried the answers here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394263/batch-print-with-printer-preset-in-macos

I have tried some of the answers (the option key trick seems to not work) but not all. Thanks for pointing out! I will definitely give these answers a try. All in all, it still seems quite complicated…

I'd agree that batch printing with options ought to be something that macOS would do effortlessly out of the box.

And I am fine with buying an app. Can’t find.

This may not be the most simple method, but here's exactly how I would do it:

Open a single PDF document in Preview.

Display the sidebar, if necessary (View -> Thumbnails)

Select all of the rest of the documents in Finder as a group, then drag them to the sidebar, adding them as pages to the PDF document

Repeat step 3 for any additional documents


The end result is you should have a single PDF document with all of the pages combined in it, which you can then print with one single print command.


It's worth noting that this copies each document into the destination document, so it doesn't modify the original documents, only the one you have open and are copying in to.

Done this. Also used a macro to print which worked - back with Excel 4 macros...

It won’t work, will it? Indeed, I want each of the document to be stapled by itself and not with all the other documents.

Ah, this is an important detail. The printer is doing the stapling for you?

Yes, the printer (of my school, I’m a teacher) is doing the stapling.

n that case you are likely limited, because the printer has to know to staple each item at the document level, and so you must send a print command for each staple level. Usually the way this would be handled is by grabbing each set of documents after they print (as they come out) and stapling them.
If you are really looking for an automated solution, you might be able to record something that is repeating using a tool such as https://www.macrorecorder.com/ to do what you need.
